# React webapp looks for assets at root

Tags: reactjs, nginx

I'm running a regular react webapp. It's deployed under `www.example.com/books/` the local version of the app works as intended, however the deployed version loads the `index.html` as intended but then it looks for javascript files at `www.example.com` instead of looking at `www.example.com/books/`

Everything is deployed in nginx and running inside a docker container.

Nginx conf:

```
server {
  listen 80;

  location /books/ {
    alias /usr/share/nginx/html/;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    auth_basic "Restricted Content";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
  }

}
```